# createEntityManager - per request or per application?

Tags: playorm

Using Astyanax alone I know we have a connection pool easily set up. However, I am not sure what happens when you do
NoSqlEntityManager other = factory.createEntityManager();
    or
NoSqlSession session = mgr.getSession();

- Should I create an entityManager every time I need a connection?
- Or should I have just 1 EM and create a session per query?

more words since so not letting me save :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create EntityManager for every webrequest in a web application or for every unit of work in a non-web application.  It is exactly like Hibernate's EntityManager and also maintains a first level cache.

During one webrequest, you typically then make 1-4 queries.

Just like hibernate NoSqlEntityManager maintains a first level cache (which from my experience gets quite a few cache hits when reading in objects).